# How to style my custom Fivestar field?

Tags: 7, views, theming

After having solved [How to calculate the average Fivestar rating correctly?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205307/how-to-calculate-the-average-fivestar-rating-correctly), I have a computed field *Average score* that displays the average score of a node. I sometimes want to display this field in a View as a rating (e.g. 4.2/5) and add some more markup to it. For the moment, I have different templates of the form **views-view-field--MY-VIEW--field-average-score.tpl.php** with the same code:

```
<?php $rating = round(($output/100) * 5, 1); ?>
<span>
  <span class="star"></span><span><?php print $rating . '/5'; ?></span>
</span>
```

Having all these duplicate templates seems silly to me. Is there a way to only have one and somehow point out which *Average score* fields should be styled accordingly? Simply using **views-view-field--field-average-score.tpl.php** is not what I want, since I don't always want to style *Average score* like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can do it like this:

Use **view-field--field-average-score.tpl.php** which will affect all views that have this field, but we can add an if statement to target the views you only want the special markup.

Ex: In here we check if it has view_name with block_1 OR view_name_2 with block_1

```
<?php if (($view->name == 'view_name' && $view->current_display == 'block_1') || ($view->name == 'view_name_2' && $view->current_display == 'block_1'): ?>
<?php $rating = round(($output/100) * 5, 1); ?>
<span>
  <span class="star"></span><span><?php print $rating . '/5'; ?></span>
</span>
<?php else: ?>
<?php print $output; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In case you are wondering, `current_display` is the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)

The `$view->current_display` check is optional. This is so it only affects a certain Display of block/page that is inside your view.

So for line 1, you could use this instead:

```
<?php if ($view->name == 'view_name' || $view->name == 'view_name_2'): ?>
```

If you want to affect all blocks/pages that are inside these 2 views.